# How can I use iCloud to synchronize a UIdocument files (saved in local document directory) between my apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, icloud, uidocument

I have an application that is saving the couple of UIDocumnet files in local document directory and display the UIdocument data.

I want to sync this document directory folder (Each and every file saved locally) with icloud on Button Press Event. I am not able to find any support for synchronizing locally saved document with icloud. I am scratching my head since last few days.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Apple provides *extensive* documentation on this topic, and it's all built in to Xcode. A good starting point is [**Managing the Life Cycle of a Document**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html). The basic steps are:

1. Create the document locally
2. Use `NSFileManager` to move the document to iCloud
3. Use `NSMetadataQuery` to find existing iCloud documents.
4. Use `NSFileManager` again to download documents from iCloud.

There are also numerous WWDC sessions on the topic over the past 2-3 years, available to anyone with a current Apple developer account.